# Send ToastNotification to remote computer

Tags: .net, windows-8, nlog

Is there any way to send a toast notification to a remote computer.
I want to write a NLog Target that shows a (Windows8) Toast on a remote computer.

I have no idea how to accomplish this task does any one have a solution or some info on the subject?

If possible i would prefer if this was done without and extra app/program running on the computer showing the toast..

Answer (score 3):

It sound like that you want is push notifications. Unfortunately you can not show toasts without having an app registered to receive push notifications. The good news is, the app itself doesn't need to be running in order to show toasts.

[Documentation on push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868244%28v=win.10%29.aspx) should provide you with good starting point.